# Equidistribution of the orbit $\{\text{diag}(t^a,t^{-a})\Lambda \}_{t>0}$ for a.e. $\Lambda\in \text{SL}(2,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, homogeneous-spaces

$\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$It is well-known that geodesic flow $g_t=\{\diag(e^t,e^{-t}) \}_{t>0}$ acts ergodically (actually mixing) on $\SL(2,\mathbb R)$ (Howe–Moore theorem) and thus  for almost all lattice $\Lambda\in X:=\SL(2,\mathbb R)/{\SL(2,\mathbb Z)}$ and any $f\in C_c(X)$, we have

$$\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(g_t.\Lambda)\,dt =\int_X f(x) \, d\mu(x),$$
where $\mu$ is the $\SL(2,\mathbb R)$ invariant probability Haar measure on $\SL(2,\mathbb R)/{\SL(2,\mathbb Z)}$.

Now what happens if we replace $(g_t)$ with $(h_t):=\{\diag(t^a,t^{-a})\}_{t>0}$ (assume $a>0$)? Do we still have for almost all $\Lambda \in X$ and **compactly supported continuous** function $f$ (in particular $f(h_t.\Lambda)$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and thus the limit for the normalization by $T$ of this integral and the integral starting from $t=1$ are the same) that

$$\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(h_t.\Lambda) \, dt=\int_X f(x) \, d\mu(x)? \tag{*}\label{star}$$

Or the equidistribution depends on the choice of $a>0$ or there is no equidistribution at all?

The difference between $g_t$ and $h_t$ is that $g_{s+t}=g_s g_t$ but $h_{st}=h_t h_s$ and thus not a one-parameter subgroup. Ideally, I wish someone had studied an analog of Weyl's criterion for the equidistribution of $\diag\{f(t),1/f(t)\}_{t>0} \cdot \Lambda$ on $X$.

By the way, I know one can perform a change of variable on $\frac{1}{T} \int_0^Tf(g_t.\Lambda) \, dt$ to reparametrize it to become $h_t$ action. But that is not what I meant. My question is about \eqref{star}, literally.

---

I hope those who claim that this is a poorly stated question could provide some solid evidence showing for example when $a=1$ the a.e. equidistribution is impossible.

Comment: Your integral has a convergence problem at 0. If you integrate from 1 instead, you can perform a simple change of variables to reduce it to the known case but with a different integrand, which shows that such a formula cannot hold.

Comment: @echo The convergence problem shouldn't be an issue since $f$ is compactly supported and thus zero as $t\to 0$. When I perform a change of variable, the integrand and limits of integral are both changed. One can't conclude such a formula no longer holds simply because of this.

Comment: The convergence problem remains, as the function is of compact support on $X$, which does not imply that the function in $t$ is of compact support. If it were, the theorem would be false. Also, my argument keeps, as the claim is for all $f$.

Comment: @Echo Since $f\in C_c(X)$, it is bounded by some $M_f$. Therefore $\frac{1}{T}\int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)\Lambda)dt \le \frac{M_f}{T} \to 0$ as $T\to \infty$. I couldn't get your point for continuity when $t\to 0$. It doesn't matter if the integral starts at $0$ or $1$.

Comment: This question doesn’t make any kind of sense, even with the “reasonable” modification of $t\geq 1$. One can move into the analogous discrete average where one can easily see that one sums over $O(\log N)$ elements but normalizes by $N$.

Comment: @Asaf I don't understand what you meant by "doesn't make any sense".  Do you mean for different $f$ we have different convergence outcomes? Can you construct any examples showing the almost everywhere equidistribution is too much to hope for? without just saying looking at the discrete analog? I also don't understand that discrete analog you mentioned. Why are there $O(\log N)$ terms?

Comment: @Asaf Thanks for your effort. But in your example (you meant $\log T = \log_2 T$ probably), when you write $\frac{1}{T}\int_{t=1}^{T}h_{t}.f(x)dt = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=0}^{\log T -1}h_{2^{i}}.F(x)$, what do you mean by $h_{2^{i}}.F(x)$? In order to make this equality true, I have to interpret this term as $\int_{2^i}^{2^{i+1}}h_{t}.f(x)dt$. If this is the case, then when you take $f\equiv 1$ (well, $f$ has to be compactly supported...) the individual summand is getting bigger and bigger with $i$. Therefore, you cannot conclude $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=0}^{\log T -1}h_{2^{i}}.F(x) \to 0$.

Comment: But I suppose when you were writing this, you were treating $h_{2^{i}}.F(x)=\int_1^2 h_{t}.f(2^i x)dx$ and when $f\equiv 1$ we have $h_{2^{i}}.F(x)=1$ and thus $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=0}^{\log T -1}h_{2^{i}}.F(x)= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=0}^{\log T -1} 1 \to 0$ and therefore you wanted to conlude $\frac{1}{T}$ is not the right normalization. But under this interpretation, your identity $\frac{1}{T}\int_{t=1}^{T}h_{t}.f(x)dt = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=0}^{\log T -1}h_{2^{i}}.F(x)$ also fails! So your example is not valid.

Comment: @Asaf As I said above, this interpretation would violate your identity $\frac{1}{T}\int_{t=1}^{T}h_{t}.f(x)dt = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=0}^{\log T -1}h_{2^{i}}.F(x)$. Since LHS is $\frac{1}{T}(T-1)$ and RHS is $\frac{1}{T}(\log T)$

Answer (score 0):

This thing cannot hold no matter what.
As Echo rightfully commented, the expression doesn't even compile when $t=0$. It is true one might temper the integral away from $0$, but that's not what you asked. This asymmetry between $[1,T]$ and $[0,1]$ suggests something fishy is going on in general.

Anyhow, I will demonstrate the answer is **STRONGLY NEGATIVE** even with the "reasonable" adjustment (say taking $t\in [1,T]$).

What follows holds for any lattice $\Gamma\leq SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Define $A_{T}f(x\Gamma) = \frac{1}{T}\int_{1}^{T}g_{t}.f(x\Gamma)dt$. [I will call the modified family $g_{t}$ as well, the usage of $h_{t}$ here is rather confusing as this is usually reserved for the horocyclic flow].

Assume now that $f\in L^{2}_{0}$. A computation a-la Furstenberg shows
$$ \left\lVert A_{T}f\right\rVert^{2} = \frac{1}{T^2}\int_{1\leq t,t' \leq T } \left\langle g_{t}.f,g_{t'}.f\right\rangle dtdt' = \frac{1}{T^2}\int_{1\leq t,t' \leq T } \left\langle g_{1/t'}g_{t}.f.f\right\rangle dtdt'.$$
The last expression shows something is fishy (as this is not a unitary family of operators, otherwise it should have been $-t'$).
So we get
$$ \left\lVert A_{T}f\right\rVert^{2} = \frac{1}{T^2}\int_{1\leq t,t' \leq T } \left\langle g_{t/t'}.f.f\right\rangle dtdt'.$$
So we just need to analyze this "convolution" integral over the matrix coefficients.
Assume now that $f$ is nice (in general, one can say more here with a proper assumption over the automorphic support of $f$).

By HC's bound, we have that $\left\lvert \left\langle g_{r}.f,f\right\rangle\right\rvert \ll_{f} e^{-s\cdot a \cdot \log(r^{\pm})},$ for some spectral gap $s=s(\Gamma)>0$.

We split the set of parameters into two subsets, one is when $\left\lvert t/t'\right\rvert^{\pm} -1 \gg R$ and the complement.
The matrix coefficients over the first set have some decay.
The second set is the culprit, for that set, one only have a negligible decay if any.
Now the area estimate for the second set is $O(T^{2}\cdot R)$. So if one picks some $R$ say, there's a set of positive density (essentially $O(R)$) such that the $L^{2}$ norm is greater than $O(R)\cdot \min_{\left\lvert \ell\right\rvert \leq R}\left\lvert \langle g_{\ell}.f,f \rangle \right\rvert$, the rest is trivially bounded by $O(R^{-a\cdot s})$.
As such, we see that $\left\lVert A_{T}f\right\rVert_{L^{2}}^2 \gg R^{1-a\cdot s}$, which clearly does not decay with $T$. Hence there is not even convergence in mean.

This is in sharp contrast with the regular parameterization, where one have $\left\lvert t’-t\right\rvert \leq R$ is of size $O(R\cdot T)$, hence the integral along that diagonal becomes negligible as $T\to\infty$.

Comment: Are you concluding that for any lattice, there is no convergence? But apparently for the lattice $\mathbb Z^2$ and the action of $a_t=\text{diag}\{t, 1/t\}$, there is a full escape of mass for the flow $a_t \mathbb Z^2$ and $A_T f$ does go to zero. Or did I understand your point wrongly?

Comment: I demonstrated that in $L^{2}_{0}$, the operator $A_{T}$ does not converge to zero… So definitely there is no pointwise result.